# on.change text box to confirm update of information

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database form that is linked to a table.

Users create records where data is inputted into a field called "seq.".

The users will need to change selected fields within the record, but the "seq." needs to remain unchanged, under most circumstances.

I want to have an on.change event where a message box comes up stating "you are about to change the seq. field, please confirm change" that makes the user aware that they may be changing this information.I need help creating this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use the Control's Before Update event. It should disallow any changes, if it is meant to be.

```
Private Sub controlName_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If MsgBox("You are about to change the seq. field, please confirm change" _
                vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Changes have been confirmed."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really glad that you posted this simple example, I had never really seen a working example of using the Cancel variable (nor even really knew what it was for). Thanks!